# A validation is not allowing my form to submit

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation

I'm currently creating a custom form to submit data to the database however my aim is I don’t want the submit button to work till user clicks on the checkbox to accepted the terms and conditions, if the user tries to submit without clicking the check box message should pop up below is a piece of code I used. However when I click on the check box and click submit, the form does not submits the message box keeps popping up on the checkbox that says "Please indicate that you accept the Terms and Conditions"… Not sure what seems to be an issue or i'm missing something.

```html
  

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <a href="TermsPage.txt" style="color:green"><u><b >CLICK TO VIEW OUR TERMS AND CONDITIONS </b> </u></a>  &nbsp;
            <input id="field_terms" type="checkbox"  name="terms" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("field_terms").setCustomValidity("Please indicate that you accept the Terms and Conditions");
            </script>
            <br />
            <button type="button">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prevent the form submission.

This tells the browser that the form should not be allowed to submit without the checkbox checked.

```js
  function checkForm(form)
  {

    if(!form.terms.checked) {
      alert("Please indicate that you accept the Terms and Conditions");
      form.terms.focus();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
<p><input type="checkbox" name="terms"> I accept the <u>Terms and Conditions Linked here</u></p>
<p><input type="submit"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It might help you

```
<form method="POST" action="http://www.cs.tut.fi/cgi-bin/run/~jkorpela/echo.cgi">
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="check"  />
 <input type="submit" name="email_submit" value="submit" onclick="if(!this.form.checkbox.checked){alert('You must agree to the terms first.');return false}"  />
</form>
```